# Eclipse : impossible to import a maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project on my computer that I try to import in Eclipse.
I am clicking on

> Import existing maven project

then I select the folder where the maven project is (where the pom.xml is located), but everything is disabled, like if the project was not recognized as a maven project. I can't import it.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Try deleting any .classpath and .project files in that directory and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to go via command line on the folder containing the maven project and run

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

That should remove any Eclipse related file. Then try again to import it in Eclipse as an existing Maven project.

Comment: this doesn't work, the pom.xml file is still disabled when I try to import as a maven project. weird.

Comment: did you firstly remove it from Eclipse, then eclipse:clean, then try to import it again?